# How do I print this array that contains a tic tac toe game board?

Tags: c++

so I looked online and saw other ways to create a tic toe table but I couldn't quite understand it. I attempted to use an array to create my tic tac toe board but I can't seem to print it. Can someone tell me how to print this?

```
 string tic [6][5] = { {" 1 2 3"}, { "1 | | "}, {" _____"}, {"2 | | " }, {" _____"}, 
            {"3 | | "}};
            cout<< tic<< endl ;
            a++;
```

Everyone has their own way to do things. I am just wondering why this isn't printing out.

Okay so this is how my code looks now so that I can input Xs and Os but it doesn't seem to be printing to one line.

```
int a = 0;

    while (a < rounds){
        string tic [6][6] = { {" ","1"," ","2"," ","3"}, { "1"," ","|"," ","|"," "}, {" ","_","_","_","_","_"}, {"2"," ","|"," ","|"," " }, {" ","_","_","_","_","_"},{"3"," ","|"," ","|"," "}};

        for(int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<6; ++j)
                cout << tic[i][j];
        a++;
```

Comment: are you familiar with loops ?

Comment: I am? But I need to use these characters?

Comment: there is not but ! if you want to print a 2d array you must use loops

Comment: this is for a tic toe game so I will need manual input

Comment: your question was about printing array , not about reading input ...

Comment: So I should re-ask it. But I am afraid I won't ask it correctly.

Comment: Make sure to include the current output of your program, and show what output you expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a loop all over the array like this

```
for(int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
   for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        cout << tic[i][j];
```

Comment: this is not a place to learn him how to print a 2D array , if he do not familiar with the loops , he never learn programming , first try to comment , then try to answer

Comment: Damit, I can't seem to create a board.

Comment: I just want to print a board with those characters and I can't do that with a loop?

Comment: I know how to use loops though

Answer (score -1):

The key insight here is that `tic` is in fact a pointer to an array of arrays of strings.
When you try to print `tic` directly, you will get a memory address.

To print the elements of your string array, you will need to go through it and print each element, e.g. using two nested `for` loops (since your array has two dimensions).

Comment: Yes, that is al I am getting are addresses but I want the board to print out. I can't use loops with these specific characters because that would take me forever.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why "it would take you forever". `cout << tic[0][0];` prints the first string `" 1 2 3"` correctly and quickly, right? If so, the nested for loops will do that for each entry, in 3 lines of code.

Comment: haha omg *facepalm*, sorry that was silly of me. You're correct.

Comment: @Monrelle Feel free to accept & upvote the answer if this solved your issue, or edit your question to clarify further :)

Comment: I uprooted but I don't have a high reputation. Also I edited the question.

Comment: @Monrelle Note that `tic` isn't a pointer, but an array (of arrays.) The relationship between pointers and arrays is complicated in C and C++, but the two are distinct types.